# why this code doesn't give me plot line (without error)?

Tags: matlab, sigmoid

I wrote this piece of code for plotting the 'Theoretical probability of a successful search versus Jaccard similarity' figure. The output is an empty plot. I don't know what should I change. the original function is in the picture I have replaced some variables.
[this is the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXPh4.jpg)

```
clc
clear
% input paramters
b=100;
r=5;
v=2;
% function
s = linspace(0,1,0.2);
for i=0:v-1
    for j=1:size(s,2)
        sigmoid(j) = 1 - sum ((factorial(b)/(factorial(i).*factorial(b - i))).*(1-(s(j) .^r).^(b-i)).*((s(j).^r).^i));
    end
end
%plot
plot(s, sigmoid, 'linew')
xlabel('Jaccard Similarity'), ylabel('Probability of Successful Search')
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
s = linspace(0,1,0.2);
```

must replaced by

```
s = linspace(0,1,n);
```

where n is integer number represents the number of s elements. The spacing between the points is (x2-x1)/(n-1), so if you want spacing "0.2" the n will be 6.